# Graph of a function with two local maxima, a local minimum and without global minimums.

Tags: calculus, functions, maxima-minima

What would be the graph of a function with two local maxima, a local minimum and without global minimums?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: $f(x)=x^2-x^4.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just draw it . . .

Two mountain tops and a valley between, then extend the outer parts down to minus infinity.

As an example, the following piecewise function satisfies the conditions . . .
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2+x&\text{if}\;\,x < -1\\[4pt]
|x|&\text{if}\;\,-1 \le x \le 1\\[4pt]
2-x&\text{if}\;\,x > 1\\[4pt] 
\end{cases}
$$
For another example, since there was no specified requirement for continuity, the following piecewise function satisfies the conditions, and moreover, has no global minimum *and* no global maximum . . .
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2+x&\text{if}\;\,x < -1\\[4pt]
|x|&\text{if}\;\,-1 \le x \le 1\\[4pt]
2-x&\text{if}\;\,1 < x < 2\\[4pt] 
x-1&\text{if}\;\,x \ge 2
\end{cases}
$$